# Passing data between React components with no child-parent relationship?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have two views that are being rendered in separate "tabs" in my application:

In **formA.tsx** I have the first component that renders a view and stores the user inserted value in its state, and once the submit button is pressed, `submitForm()` is called:

```
class FormA extends React.Component<any, any>{
    public constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={name:''}
    }
    private submitForm(){
        //transfer data -> FormB
    }
    ...
```

In **formB.tsx** I have a different rendered view, but I want the state of FormA to be displayed here:

```
class FormB extends React.Component<any, any>{
    ...
    render(){
        return(
        <p> //the FormA state here </p>
        )
    }
```

All the information I see online are for parent-child components where this information is passed through props, but here the components are technically both parents as they do not interact with each other. How can I make this data transfer? Through an intermediate component (is this efficient)?

EDIT: I fixed this problem by using a Javascript eventBus.

Comment: One of the easier options in the case is to "life state up" to the closest common parent

Comment: You could use something like RXJS https://www.learnrxjs.io/ to accomplish this.  Essentially you're giving parts of your state over to a service that is accessible to both component.

Comment: Are form A and form B siblings of each other or are they far away in the component tree?

Comment: @SteveK no they are not siblings. I guess they can both be considered parents?

Answer (score 2):

In short, information always has to "flow down" in a React application, whether you use `props` or context.  This means that if two components need to share state, ultimately some parent component of the two needs to create that state and provide it to the two components.

This may feel limiting, but it's actually part of the "flux" paradigm that Facebook came up with when they created React.  Essentially the idea behind it is that if you keep your data always flowing in one direction, it solves a lot of bigger problems.  If you're curious, the Facebook team did a great video explaining that larger philosophy, and how it came out of the development of Facebook Messenger: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nYkdrAPrdcw.

But philosophy aside, as a practical matter the context API (which was recently *greatly* improved) enables that critical "top down" flow, while still saving you from the pain of having to use `props` to pass it through every component in-between. I'd encourage you to look into setting your shared state in a context that a parent component "provides", and then having your two components "consume" that context.

P.S. You can use a third-party library (with Redux being the most popular) to instead have "global state" shared across all your components.  However, just be aware that (as is the case with any usage of global state) there are trade-offs involved.

Redux is a *great* library (and it's creator Dan Abramov now works on React; he answered a ticket of mine a couple days ago in fact). But at the same time, recent changes to React (which he helped make; namely the new Context stuff) has made Redux much less valuable than it used to be.

The library absolutely still has value, but I would just recommend making sure you understand what "pure React" offers before adding extra complexity like Redux.

Comment: The problem is there the two components do not have a shared parent. They have their own form rendering and share nothing else other than that transfer of data at a button click. I think the Context API seems to be the more fitting solution?

Comment: *Every* component in your entire app shares a common single root component: it's the one that you call `ReactDOM.render` on (and in a `create-react-app` app it's literally called "App").  Do you have multiple render calls?

Comment: Yes, I have a different `ReactDom.render()` call on `<FormA/>`, then a separate one on  `<FormB/>`

Comment: Which I'm now just thinking that having a global store might make my life easier, especially when the only interaction they have would be this data transfer.

Comment: Really, unless you have a compelling reason not to, you should just have a single `ReactDOM.render` call.  As I said before, in `create-react-app` the template app made (in the tool *provided by the React team*) uses a single call, and so do all React apps I've seen.  You *can* use React with multiple calls, but I'd suggest that "philosophically", if you're having troubles with a framework, you can either work with it, or work against it ... eg. by trying to solve (with extra libraries) problems you create by using it "unusually" ... and working with it leads to easier code.

Comment: P.S. But also, as I said in my answer, Redux is a great library!  If you have a complex React app with serious client-side data involved, Redux offers a whole lot *more* than just global data state.  For instance, the "action-based" approach it takes can make implementing very powerful undo features much easier.  But if you use Redux, get used to many more "rules" like React's one-direction data flow. For instance, all your data needs to be "immutable" to properly use Redux.  Ultimately Redux is a great tool ... but only when it's the right one for the job (like any tool).

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like you want some kind of global state. Either

(1) you have a **common parent** component that holds the state or

(2) you use react's [Context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) to hold the state or

(3) you use a library for global state management such as [redux](https://redux.js.org/).